# Dominant terms in a multivariate Taylor expansion

Tags: asymptotics, taylor-expansion, power-series

Consider the series expansion of $\sqrt{(1+x)(1+y^2)}$ around $(x, y) = (0, 0)$.  If I naively expand it so that I keep only terms up to second order in $x$ and $y$, I get
\begin{align}
\sqrt{(1+x)(1+y^2)} &= \left[1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8} + O(x^3)\right] \left[1+\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{y^4}{8} +O(y^6)\right]\\
&\approx 1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}+\frac{y^2}{2}.
\end{align}
This is obviously wrong since looking at the lowest order terms in $x$ and $y$ we have the scaling $O(x) \sim O(y^2)$.  Hence, the third term $-x^2/8$ scales like $O(x^2) \sim O(y^4)$.  The correct expansion, which keeps all $O(y^4)$ terms is
$$
\sqrt{(1+x)(1+y^2)} = 1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}+\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{x y^2}{4}-\frac{y^4}{8} + O(x^3) + O(y^6).
$$

1. Is there a formal word for "balancing" terms and finding scales like this? I looked at [dominant balance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_dominant_balance) and intuitively it seems that, to find the scaling, what I did above was to balance the most dominant terms, i.e., $x$ and $y^2$, with each other.
2. Is there a more systematic way of doing this?

Comment: In principle it depends on the direction you go: if you assume $x$ and $y$ are comparable then the first estimate is linear in $x$ and doesn't depend on $y$ while the second is quadratic in both. The $x$ term will dominate here but that is fine (you should not insist that it balances with the first term that depends on $y$). But in a direction near the $y$ axis you could have $y^2 \gg x$, even. So this all depends on the directions you want to resolve. "Uniformizing" it so this goes away is a hard problem in typical real situations.

Comment: Another way to think about this: assume that the "1" and $x$ in my example function have units of length. This means that for the function to make dimensional sense, $y$ must have units of *square-root* of length.  If I make $x$ and $y$ dimensionless by setting $x \to x l$ and $y \to y \sqrt{l}$, with $l$ being length units, I could do the expansion systematically in $l$, to $O(l^2)$ to find the correct expansion.  I think this is also closely related to the answer @Claude Leibovici provided.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can easily turn the problem around using [directional derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative).

To give you an idea, I put here some Mathematica code

`f[x_,y_]:=Sin[x+y^2]`

`Series[f[x t,y t],{t,0,5}]`

would produce

$$tx+t^2 y^2-t^3 \frac{x^3}{6}-\frac{1}{2} t^4 \left(x^2 y^2\right)+\frac{1}{120} t^5 \left(x^5-60 x y^4\right)+O\left(t^6\right)$$ in which you will set $t=1$.

Shorter would be

`Normal[Series[f[x t,y t],{t,0,5}]] /. t->1`

Comment: Sorry, I changed my example problem, but this is an interesting idea!

Comment: Now that I think about it, I think this is equivalent to demanding that $x$ and $y^2$ must have the same physical dimensions.  Only quantities of the same dimensions can be added/subtracted and by setting $(x, y) \to (x t , y \sqrt{t})$ you're implicitly introducing dimensions into the problem, with $t$ being the "units" used to measure $x$ and $y$.